# Sonar not picking up the visual studio test report paths

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We are running SonarQube(5.0.1), with sonar.net-runner on a TFS (2010) team build.

FxCop works fine, and everything runs perfect, I see all the issues in sonar.

However, when I try to pull in the test results in sonar, I run into an issue.

When I set the property `sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths` to an absolute file of a `trx` file, it publishes my test results to sonar. **Great**.

But when I use a wild card, my test results don't get published in sonar. **Not so great**

**Configurations I've tried.**

```
#1
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=E:/Builds/1/74/TestResults/*.trx

#2
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx

#3
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=**/*.trx

#4
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=.**/*.trx
```

**Full configuration**

```
# ----- Project identification
sonar.projectVersion=2.6.0.0914
sonar.projectName=MySolution
sonar.projectKey=Company:MySolution

# ----- Use UTF-8 encoding, otherwise analysis is unable to read files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# ----- Visual studio bootstrapper
# Enable the Visual Studio bootstrapper
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true

#Define the solution to run sonar against
sonar.visualstudio.solution=MySolution.sln

#Specify the pattern of the test projects
sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=.*Test*.

#We are using custom output paths.
sonar.visualstudio.outputPaths=E:/Builds/1/74/Binaries

# ----- FxCop
sonar.cs.fxcop.aspnet=false
sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=D:/Sonar.NET/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe


# ----- Unit Test Results
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=.**/*.trx.


# This property is set because it is required by the SonarQube Runner.
# But it is not taken into account because the location of the source
# code is retrieved from the .sln and .csproj files.
sonar.sources=.
```

Comment: Did you get any update on your issue?

Comment: I tried using "sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx", but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide full path to .trx file.

`sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=../TestResults/TestResult.trx`

Answer (score 2):

When I specify full file name it works.
For example,
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=C:/MyTestSoln/TestResults/MyTest.trx

But it doesn't work when I try
"sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResults/*.trx"