# Where can I find detailed steps to analyze project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: sonarqube

newbie to Sonarqube

I have a Sonarqube instance up and running. 
How do I go about creating a project for my VS2013 solution in Sonarqube and do an analysis. (Not using any version control for now)

[image: Connected to sonarqube in VS2013]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using an unofficial Visual Studio extension for SonarQube - which I would not recommend.

Within Visual Studio 2015+ (2013 is not supported), you can use the C# Code Analysis: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+C%23+Code+Analysis

Have a look at the following page to see how to analyze your project in SonarQube (not in Visual Studio): http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

Comment: Also, could you answer this question ? I am running into the same issue , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140962/sonar-not-picking-up-the-visual-studio-test-report-paths

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the project first analysed in your sonar server, after that you can associate to that project and then it will allow you to run further local analysis. you need to have the correct permissions. please check documentation for [more](https://github.com/TeklaCorp/VSSonarQubeExtension/wiki) details